# QuickSort for sorted array

Tags: java, quicksort

Here is my code implementation for QuickSort algorithm; however, it does not work for sorted arrays. What could be the problem?

```
    public void insertionSort(ArrayList<String> data, int firstIndex,
    int numberToSort) {
    if (firstIndex + numberToSort > data.size())
        System.out.println("Index is larger then the date size");
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i < numberToSort; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (data.get(firstIndex + j).compareTo(
                        data.get(firstIndex + i)) > 0)
                    Collections.swap(data, firstIndex + i, firstIndex + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void quickSort(ArrayList<String> data, int firstIndex,
        int numberToSort) {
    if (firstIndex + numberToSort > data.size())
        System.out.println("Index is larger then the date size");
    else {
        if (numberToSort <= 16)
            insertionSort(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);
        else {
            int idx = partition(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);
            int leftSeg = idx - firstIndex;
            int rightSeg = numberToSort - leftSeg - 1;

            quickSort(data, firstIndex, leftSeg);
            quickSort(data, idx + 1, rightSeg); // This is where I get an error
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int partition(ArrayList<String> data, int firstIndex,
        int numberToPartition) {
    String pivot = data.get(firstIndex);
    int TooBigNdx = firstIndex + 1;
    int TooSmallNdx = firstIndex + numberToPartition - 1;

    while (TooBigNdx < TooSmallNdx) {
        while (TooBigNdx < TooSmallNdx
                && data.get(TooBigNdx).compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
            TooBigNdx++;
        while (TooSmallNdx > firstIndex
                && data.get(TooSmallNdx).compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            TooSmallNdx--;
        if (TooBigNdx < TooSmallNdx)
            Collections.swap(data, TooBigNdx, TooSmallNdx);
    }
    if (pivot.compareTo(data.get(TooSmallNdx)) >= 0) {
        Collections.swap(data, firstIndex, TooSmallNdx);
        return TooSmallNdx;
    }
    return firstIndex;
}
```

Every time I run I pass unsorted array, it works fine. Yet, my tester gives me an AssertionError. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could share the actual error you are seeing.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I tried this example, with some small code changes to make it easy to run. I tried within different sorted arrays as input, and I didn't see anything too obvious. Do you for which input it failed?

Your code in [online compiler IDE for java](https://kasadara.com/p/05017f7b-8e64-45d6-ab8d-8492aa69b283) 
Can you try modifying the input to see where it fails?